# where do I initialize NSMutable Dictionary?

Tags: iphone, nsmutabledictionary

I have an Array comprised of further sub-Arrays

I want to display a summary of the contents of the sub-arrays into a TableView with the count of occurrences of each entry. I have determined that the best and easiest way is through a NSMutableDictionary as an intermediate step.

I declare the dictionary in my implementation

```
@implementation ReviewViewController
{
NSMutableDictionary *dict;
}
```

and down in my methods I initialise and use it like so:

```
dict =  [NSMutableDictionary new];
[dict setObject:[Observation entryCount] forKey:[observedItem species]];
```

The swapping of key and object is deliberate as its the count I want. I'm using the fact that values are retained, but keys are overwritten, so if i swap them round i get the curation for free.

It works!, but every time the method is invoked, the Dictionary is clobbered by the re-initalization so I only get the last thing entered. Anywhere else and it falls out of scope.

if I pass it as an arguement in the method name instead, I get the message "Local declaration of 'dict' hides instance variable ". The code is already an irreducable set of parts, so

so, where is the correct place for the instantiation?

I'd love to make my contribution here as a meaningful thanks, but before I can do that I'm going to look silly with such questions.

Comment: whats in [observedItem species]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would usually initialise it in your `init` method. For a view controller this is usually the following:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString*)nibName bundle:(NSBundle*)bundle {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:bundle])) {
        dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I don't understand what you mean by "Anywhere else and it falls out of scope.". It's an instance variable. It is therefore in scope in any method in the class.

By the way, I would name your instance variables with an underscore prefix, e.g. `_dict`. This is common convention and it helps you to remember when using it that it's an instance variable.

Comment: thanks. in the meantime, the simplest of places, ViewDidLoad, did the trick, but if initWithNibName is the more conventional. I thought underscoring was only used with forcing the synthesized property. Live and learn, i just lived -twice.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is not a bad place to do it. It all depends on what the lifecycle is of that object. If it's in `viewDidLoad` then the dictionary will be initialised to a new, empty one each time the view is loaded. That might be what you want, or it might not be.